# How can you tell whether prefixed ‘in-’ is the preposition ‘in’ or Indo-European ‘in-’?

Tags: classical-latin, vowel-quantity, prefix, proto-indo-european, negation

### Background

The verb *īnsum* has the prefix *in-*. Prefixing *in*/*in-* to words, changes their meaning to ‘in’, ‘on’ *et sim.*, or ‘un-’, ‘non’ *et sim.* (ɔ:¹ negation).² However, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insum#Latin), the pronunciation of *in* changes in some context; this supported by [Lewis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=insum).

At first, my understanding was that this pronunciation change – ɔ: from [ɪ] to [ĩː] – only occurs where the prefix is *not* the preposition *in*, but the actual prefix *in-*. Even though sounding the same, they have different roots: When meaning ‘in(side)’, it is merely the preposition prefixed; when meaning ‘not’/‘[negation]’, it has the Indo-European origin [*n̥-].[5](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-#Latin) As it turns out, the pronunciation change is merely a matter of morpheme interaction.

Non of my grammars, however, even the very detailed grammar by Nils Sjöstrand (Gleerups forlag, Malmö/Lund 1960) has any details on these two differences. The only thing I can find that is mildly relevant, is in Sjöstrand § 6.2, explaining the enlonging [I’m sorry, I am not sure what the correct linguistic term is] and nasalisation of vowels in front of *ns* and *nf*.

### Question

This means that pronunciation alone is not a clue as to whether or not one is dealing with *in* prefixed, or the prefix *in-*, as they both will have their pronunciations changed based on which morphemes follow. **How can you know whether you are dealing with the preposition or the prefix, and thus the correct meaning of the word?**

### Somewhat Related

- [Understanding vowel quantity in fieri](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/understanding-vowel-quantity-in-fieri)
- [vowel length in “pro” before “f”](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/vowel-length-in-pro-before-f)

### Notes

¹ This is not a smiley; it is the symbol meaning ‘that is’, ‘may be read as’ and similar.

² Egil Kraggerud & Bjørg Tosterud: *Latinsk ordbok*, Cappelen, Oslo 1998: ‘**in** i sammensetning’.

I have added the `negation` tag, but am unsure as to its relevance. Advice on this is appreciated. It could very well be that the tag details should be updated to include questions such as this one.

Comment: I have never seen "ɔ:" meaning "that is" - where did you get it from?

Comment: I grew up with it. My granddad’s old dictionaries, printed in fraktur, were amongst those that often used it, and it is commonly known in stenography. Realising it was not common knowledge, was surprising to me.
AFAIK, it was most commonly used in areas influenced by germanic typographical tradition (such as Scandinavia); it seems to be gaining a resurgence now, with more and more people interested in typography and traditions lost.
Some links:
http://www.typografi.org/forklaringstegn/forklaringstegn.html
https://macbasics.wordpress.com/2015/02/22/typografi-det-glemte-forklaringstegnet/

Comment: Given that you're writing in English, for an audience familiar with Latin, why not use a convention commonly used in English (for example "i.e.", short for "id est")? Unfortunately, using "ɔ:" is confusing, especially in a site with a linguistics flavour, because readers are far more likely to interpret it as an IPA vowel than your intended meaning - certainly I was confused on my first reading :)

Comment: Two reasons in particular: 1) Realising that the current young students do not have knowledge of it, appears to be a matter of age. 2) Spreading the knowledge. When re-entering uni, I thought it was common knowledge – after all, I had known about it since I was a tiny kid – but soon realised it was not. I assumed this was a matter of age, as people of my own age (in their 30s) were familiar with it. Being that this is a classicist’s site, I assumed this way of spreading knowledge would be appreciated; I hope this was the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The negative prefix *in-* typically attaches to an adjective, while the prepositional prefix *in-* typically attaches to a verb. The main complication to this distribution is the existence of adjectives derived from verbs (or at least, participle forms that look very similar to adjectives) and nouns derived from adjectives or from verbs. But if you're looking at a finite verb form such as "īnsum", you can be fairly confident that the prefix *in-* does not express negation.

For either prefix, the vowel is long before *ns* or *nf*, and short otherwise. There is no difference in pronunciation between the two prefixes spelled *in-*. They also share a number of alternative spellings representing assimilated pronunciations, such as *im-* *ir-* *il-*, which likewise are pronounced the same for both prefixes regardless of the meaning. (Many words can take either an assimilated or unassimilated spelling, as discussed at [-NL- and -LL- in Classical Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/nl-and-ll-in-classical-latin) ; I'm not sure whether the rates of assimilated spellings differ between the two prefixes.) The negative prefix has a [rare form *ig-*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11323) that I don't think occurs as a form of the prepositional prefix.

#### Finite verbs are very rarely negated with *in-*

"[Prefix Derivation in Latin](http://cis01.central.ucv.ro/revista_scol/site_ro/2012/lexicologie/dinu.pdf)", by Dana DINU, says that the negative prefix *in-* "does not apply to verbs".

This is almost always true. (There are *slightly* more exceptions than I would have guessed). So far, I've found only the following possible exceptions, some or all of which may actually be back-formed from related adjectives (rather than derived from affixing *in-* directly to the verb):

- ***ignōscō,*** "pardon, forgive", is explained in some sources as coming from the negative prefix and *(g)nōscō.* For example, [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dignosco) says "lit., not to wish to know, not to search into; hence, with esp. reference to a fault or crime, *to pardon*". I have asked a separate [question about *ignōscō*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/what-is-the-correct-etymology-of-ign%C5%8Dsc%C5%8D-pardon) to try to determine the explanation for this unusual case.
- ***improbō***, "disapprove, condemn". I'm guessing it is a backformation from *improbātus* < *in-* + *probātus.*
- ***indecet, "be indecent, unseemly",*** mentioned by Knapp (1917) when discussing *ignosco.* Looks like a likely backformation from *indecēns.* This verb seems to be extremely rare.
- ***inobaudiō/inoboediō***, "disobey". I'm guessing it is a backformation from *inobaudiens/oediens*. Seems rather rare.

  Example: Tertullian's *Adversus Marcionem*:

  > Cum ergo mandato diceret populo, Ecce ego mitto angelum meum ante faciem tuam, qui te custodiat in via et introducat in terram quam paravi tibi, intende illi et exaudi eum, ne **inobaudieris** eum; non enim celabit te, quoniam nomen meum super illum est

#### Participle forms can often be negated with *in-*, but possibly only when they are actually participial adjectives

Here is a quote I found that indicates that in Classical Latin, *non* was used to negate verbal participles, while *in-* appears as a negative prefix for participial adjectives. (If you don't understand what those terms mean, it might help to look at my question about [how these two categories of participial forms were distinguished in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6462/how-can-participles-inflected-forms-be-distinguished-from-deverbal-adjectives).)

> in Classical Latin the synchronic negative of e.g. *patiens* ‘enduring’
> is *non patiens*, whereas participles with a negative prefix are synchronically non-participial adjectives, e.g. *impatiens* ‘impatient’.

(p. 30, "[Negated Participles in Rgvedic Sanskrit and Proto-Indo-European](http://users.ox.ac.uk/%7Eshug1472/IIJ_054_01_1075-Lowe_print-1.pdf)," by John J. Lowe, *Indo-Iranian Journal* 54 (2011) 19-38)

If this rule is true, it would make the distribution of *non* and *in-* negation in Latin closely analogous to the distribution of *not* and *un-* negation in English for participial forms.

Since participle forms can also contain the prepositional prefix *in-,* [there are some cases of ambiguity between the two *in-* prefixes](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11348/can-in-mean-both-in-and-no).

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. Given this be true, you could in fact with some _a priori_ knowledge – as you explain: is the latter part of the word a verb or adjective – tell whether we are dealing with _in-_ or _in_. Do you have any sources?

Comment: With regards to knowing what you are dealing with by pronunciation, I specifically mention this is not possible in the question.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I will have a read and try to correct my phrasing. The question was rewritten a couple of times.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect that which is stated under the questions heading. I apologise for inconsistency.

Comment: @sumelic: Thanks for this up-date. Chances are that I've just answered a question on a related issue (e.g., _oratio inscripta est_ is ambiguous: cf. (I) 'the speech is unwritten' and (II) 'the speech was inscribed/signed' (e.g., with the author's name)). Your A nicely explains that _oratio inscripta est_, in the former reading (i.e., when the neg. prefix is involved) cannot be interpreted as a VERBAL passive but rather as an ADJECTIVAL one. If so, one would expect that no agent by-phrase can be added in _oratio inscripta est_, understood as an adjectival passive. Is that correct for Latin?

Comment: @sumelic: e.g., cf. the contrast in English between these two adjectival passives: "*The letter was unwritten by Mary" vs. (?) "The letter remained unwritten by the lawyers" (NB: the latter drawn from [http: //academia.edu/1368590/Syntactic_affixation] ). I was wondering why the latter sounds better (though perhaps a bit dubious) compared to the former, which sounds awful. What about "This question remains uncontested by any scholar in the field"? I'm not a native speaker of English but it sounds ok to me.

Comment: @Mitomino: Well, I'm not actually sure that the agent by-phrase criterion is a reliable distinction between verbal and adjectival participles, because of examples like the one that you gave (I agree that "uncontested by any scholar in the field" sounds fine). And Greg Lee also posted a comment agreeing that *by __* can appear in non-verbal constructions beneath my answer here: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/20721/5581

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I don't believe there's evidence for any difference in pronunciation between prefixes and prepositions. There does seem to be a difference in inscriptional spelling (prefixes are rarely separated by interpuncts), but this doesn't hold precisely for compounds of *est* where they often are; outside inscriptions prepositions are often written together. If we're dealing with a phonetic process, then no difference should be expected as prepositions are prosodically part of the lexical word. A difference can exist only if we're dealing with lexical allomorphy, but the proof of this would be phonetic

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: I don't think the lengthening of vowels before ns/nf was a phonetic process in the Classical Latin era, but instead a morphophonological rule. So it would be like the difference in vowel quality between con-and cum. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I would say you are :P)) Que Fortson 2008 : 126 "note also the use of “I longa” or extra-tall I in inscriptional spellings of the preposition *in* before nouns beginning with a fricative, indicating lengthening of the *i* by the normally word-internal rule that lengthens vowels before a nasal plus fricative: *In saliare carmen* Mon. Anc. 10, *Insuos* CIL II 1503 (written as one word), *In super* CIL X 1781 (105 B.C.) (Christiansen 1889, 43)".

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: Thank you for the reference! That is suggestive (although not conclusive). I’ll delete that portion of my answer, which was an uncited side comment.

Comment: Until very recently, _un-_ in English only attached to verbs when they were about fastening, wrapping, or closing: untie, unlock, unwrap, unfasten, undress, unbutton, (apart from a few literary rarities such as _unsay_), but it was freely added to adjectives. This has changed in the last twenty years with the invention of graphical user interfaces, so many actions which were not reversible have become so in that context.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's possible to distinguish *in* meaning "in" from PIE *en and *in-* meaning "not" from PIE *n̥ from pronunciation alone.  It's well known that the /i/ in *in-* lengthens when followed by certain consonsant combinations such as "ns" and "nf", but as far as I know, that is purely phonetically determined and has nothing to do with the ancestral morpheme.

So, basically, there is no *a priori* way of distinguishing the two cases.

Comment: The vowel lengthening is supported by multiple grammars (e.g. Sjöstrand § 6.2.2), so I agree with you on that. But I would find it surprising if there are no grammarians who ever commented on this seeming (unless having knowledge of PIE, which they didn’t) incongruency. Could there perhaps be anything to gather from ancient sources? Your answer still deserves upvotes, for noting the lengthening in front of _ns_ and _nf_, which learned about after reading your answer.

Comment: @CannedMan: what incongruency are you referring to?  That the I in _in_ can be short in some phonetic environments and long in others?

Comment: The inconsistency I am talking about, is the (theoretical?) possibility of words that are both homographs _and_ homophones having different meanings. One could for instances think of a word such as _inesse_ existing in two forms, both written and pronounced the same way, but one meaning ‘be in’ and the other ‘un-be’, ɔ: either ‘not to be’ or ‘cause to cease to exist’.