# What is the correct etymology of ignōscō "pardon"?

Tags: etymology, verbs, prefix, negation

The verb *ignōscō,* with the meaning "pardon, forgive", is explained in some sources as coming from the negative prefix *in-* and *(g)nōscō.* For example, [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dignosco) says "lit., not to wish to know, not to search into; hence, with esp. reference to a fault or crime, *to pardon*". [Page 6 of this handout](https://www.usu.edu/markdamen/Latin1000/Presentation/transcriptions/35T.pdf) also explains it this way.

But [the negative prefix *in-* is not usually applied to finite verbs](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/7468/9). I found a passage by C. Knapp from 1917 that addresses this topic:

> there are extremely few *finite verb-forms* which show the negative prefix *in.* One finds it hard to recall any example save *indecet.* The difficulty set up by this fact of Latin word-formation is so great that various more or less complicated explanations of the etymology of *ignosco* have been suggested. However, there is a tendency at present to return to the explanation that the word was made up of the negative prefix *in* and *(g)nosco.* It is pointed out that as an intermediary to such a form as *indecet* lies the adjective *indecens* [...] Back of *ignosco* may lie *ignotus,* as the intermediary form.

("[The Teaching of Vergil in Secondary Schools](https://books.google.com/books?id=RpQNAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=%22ignosco%22AcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)", October 8 1917, in *The Classical Weekly,* Volume XI, New York, 1917-1918, p. 12)

Can anyone tell me about more recent scholarship on this topic?

Comment: see Ernout and Meillet (s.v. ignosco) https://archive.org/details/DictionnaireEtymologiqueDeLaLangueLatine/page/n161

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, Alex B. referred to the 2001 *Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue latine* by Alfred Ernout and Antoine Meillet, which contains the following passage:

> Les grammairiens latins voyaient dans *ignōscere* un composé avec le préfixe privatif *in-*; cf. la glose *ignoscere : non noscere,* [Loewe, *Prodromus* 409](https://archive.org/details/ProdromusCorporisGlossariorumLatinorum/page/n431), et [Thes. gloss. emend. s. u. *ignōscō*](https://archive.org/details/corpusglossarior06linduoft/page/538). Mais la négation *in-* ne s'emploie pas devant un verbe, cf. plus loin sous *in-*, et c'est arbitrairement que l'on suppose (encore récemmant [Immisch, Glotta, 19, 16-24](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40265285)) que *ignōscō* aurait été créé sur *ignōscēns* (*sīs, fuās*) ; l'exemple de *indecet* formé sur *indecēns* n'est pas probant, car *indecet* est rare et d'apparaît pas avant Pline le Jeune, tandis que *ignōscō* est ancient et usuel. D'autre part, le participe présent n'est pas d'un usage tellement fréquent ; et, sémantiquement, il marque un état qui dure. *Ignōscēns sīs* ne saurait donc se dire dans le sens de « pardonne » : quand Térence dit *animus ignoscentior,* Heaut. 635, il l'emploie comme adjectif pour marquer une disposition de l'esprit avec le sens de « porté au pardon ». Le grec a également avec le même sens un autre préverbe : συγγιγνώσκω, συγγνώμη; 
>   ceci suggère un développement de sens tel que « s'accorder avec, sympathiser ». Wackernagel, Mél. Danielsson, p. 383 sqq., a rapproché avec ingéniosité *ignosco* de skr. *anujñā* « permettre ». *Ignōscō* renfermerait un préverbe *in-* comparable au skr. *anu-,* que M. Leumann propose de voir aussi dans *inueniō, inuidiō* ; mais l'existence de ce préverbe dans ces mots est des plus douteuses, et le passage de **enu* a *in-* malaisé à admettre. On a proposé **in-gnōscō,* mais le sens n'est pas expliqué par là.

([p. 308](https://archive.org/details/DictionnaireEtymologiqueDeLaLangueLatine/page/n161))

My translation (with [help from jlliagre on French SE for the translation of « porté au pardon »](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/38083/6881)):

> The Latin grammarians saw in *ignōscere* a compound with the privative prefix *in-*; cf. the gloss *ignoscere : non noscere,* [Loewe, *Prodromus* 409](https://archive.org/details/ProdromusCorporisGlossariorumLatinorum/page/n431), and [Thes. gloss. emend. s. u. *ignōscō*](https://archive.org/details/corpusglossarior06linduoft/page/538). But the negation *in-* is not used before a verb, cf. below under *in-,* and it is arbitrary to suppose (as recently as [Immisch, Glotta, 19, 16-24](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40265285)) that *ignōscō* would have been created based on *ignōscēns (sīs, fuās)* ; the example of *indecet* formed based on *indecēns* is not compelling, because *indecet* is rare and does not appear before Pliny the Younger, while *ignōscō* is old and usual. Furthermore, the usage of the present participle is not so frequent, and semantically, it marks a continuing state. *Ignōscēns sīs* cannot therefore mean "pardon": when Terence says *animus ignoscentior,* Heaut. 635, he uses it as an adjective to mark a disposition of the spirit with the sense of "inclined to give pardon". Greek has likewise with the same sense another prefix:  συγγιγνώσκω, συγγνώμη; which suggests a development of sense such as "agree with, sympathize". Wackernagel, Mél. Danielsson, p. 383 sqq., ingeniously compared *ignōscō* and Sanskrit *anujñā* "permit". *Ignōscō* would contain a prefix *in-* comparable to the Sanskrit *anu-,* that M. Leumann proposes can be seen also in *inueniō, inuidiō* ; but the existence of this prefix in these words is of the greatest doubt, and the passage from **enu* to *in-* not easy to admit. **In-gnōscō* has been proposed, but this does not explain the meaning.

Comment: Thanks for translating the entry, sumelic. I hope you don't mind my adding some links. - feel free to undo it.

Comment: M. Leumann should be Leumann, Manu. "Lateinische Laut- Und Formenlehre 1955—1962." Glotta 42, no. 1/2 (1964): 69-120 (he discusses ignoscere on page 110). http://www.jstor.org/stable/40265932.https://www.jstor.org/stable/40265932

Comment: and a more detailed summary of relevant research in Walde and Hoffmann https://archive.org/details/walde/page/n709 I'm afraid nothing substantial, of significance has been proposed/changed since then

Answer (score 1):

As for more recent scholarship on this topic, I recommend you to take a look at the following monograph by G. Haverling, who is THE expert on *-sco* verbs.

HAVERLING, Gerd (2000). *On sco-Verbs, Prefixes and Semantic Functions. A Study in the Development of Prefixed and Unprefixed Verbs from Early to Late Latin*. Studia Graeca et Latina Gothoburgensia, 64.  Göteborg: Acta Universitatis Gothoburgensis.

Interestingly (or perhaps I should rather say "Quite surprisingly"), this scholar appears to claim that the prefix of *ignosco* is not the negative prefix *IN-* (as has traditionally been assumed) but rather the lative prefix *IN-*. This opinion is shared by Prof. Benjamín García-Hernández (another important Latinist scholar who has worked on the topic of Latin preverbs quite extensively: e.g., [García-Hernández 1989](https://www.academia.edu/7174291/Les_pr%C3%A9verbes_latins)). However, as pointed out in [his review of Haverling's (2000) book/**page 131**](https://adw-goe.de/fileadmin/dokumente/forschungsprojekte/ortsnamen_rhein_elbe/Publikationen_Udolph_PDF/2001-2005/316._Udolph_Rez._zu_Anreiter._Kratylos.pdf), he is not convinced by Haverling's proposal of deriving the meaning of *forgiving* from the ingressive meaning of *beginning to get to know*. Unfortunately, he does not offer any alternative proposal.

Pending a convincing explanation, I'd buy Knapp's point quoted in your post. After all, on the basis that the stative verb ***ignoro*** is formed from the prefixed adjective ***ignarus*** (<*in+gnarus*), why not to assume that an analogical process could derive the verb ***ignosco*** from ***ignotus*** via **backformation** (along with the polysemous change above taken from Lewis and Short: "lit., not to wish to know, not to search into; hence, with esp. reference to a fault or crime, *to pardon*")?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't quite understand what García-Hernández was saying about *insuesco* and *immanesco.* Lewis and Short doesn't define *[insuesco](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=insuesco)* as having a negative meaning, even though *[insuetus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinsuetus2)* does have such a meaning. Is L&S missing an entry for another verb *insuesco* that does have a negative meaning?

Comment: Like you, I was also surprised when I read these comments on _insuesco_ and _immanesco_. I'm afraid the best we can do is to consult the voluminous monograph by Haverling (2000) directly (unfortunately, now I don't have it on hand). García-Hernández says that the discussion of these verbs is on pages 378ff. But what is really intriguing is that Haverling, THE expert on these verbs, says that the prefix IN- of _ignosco_ is not the one that expresses negation.

Comment: Grrr! Google books only allows me to read the following sentence: "scholars have held different views on the formation of _ignosco_" on page 379.  It also mentions the work by Keller (1992). I guess it's the following:  Madeleine Keller (1992). _Les verbes latins à infectum en -sc-, étude morphologique à partir des formations attestées dès l'époque classique_. Collection LATOMUS volume 216. https://www.persee.fr/doc/igram_0222-9838_1994_num_62_1_3105_t1_0060_0000_3